# Calling methods in swift (Method doesnt finish before next line)

Tags: ios, json, swift, dictionary, methods

Trying to pull in some JSON data from an API and then save that to core data.

My current method of doing this is to pull in the JSON data and return that array which ill then iterate and save to core data.

Pull in Data: (Works fine)

```
func getPlayerDataFromAPI() -> [Dictionary<String,AnyObject>]{
    let url: String = "http://api.fantasy.nfl.com/v1/players/stats?"
    let request : NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest()
    var jsonData = [Dictionary<String,AnyObject>]()
    request.HTTPMethod = "GET"
    request.URL = NSURL(string: url)
    session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data, response, error) -> Void in

        do {
            let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
            if (jsonResult != nil) {
                if let playerData = jsonResult?["players"] as? [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>]{

                    jsonData = playerData
                    print(jsonData.count)
                }
            } else {
                print("No Data")
            }
        }
        catch {
            print("Error Occured")
        }
        }.resume()
    return jsonData;
}
```

And then I wanted to test the returned Dictionary to ensure it was being populated:

```
func saveData(){
    let players = getPlayerDataFromAPI()
    print(players.count)
}
```

I call saveData() in the viewController viewDidLoad method and get an empty dictionary... Moments later, the print statement in the JSON function prints.

```
0
1427
```

Is there a reason the getPlayerDataFromAPI() function doesnt finish before the print(count) is being called? Do I have this wrong logically? I always get an empty dictionary returned in this instance and thats no good.

Comment: Do you understand what "asynchronous" means? Do a search on SO. This has been dealt with here many, many times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to synchronously return the results of an asynchronous function. `session.dataTaskWithRequest` is passed a closure, which doesn't execute until the request completes. So your `jsonData = playerData` statement doesn't get executed until after your `getPlayerDataFromAPI()` function has already returned (at which point `jsonData` is still the empty dictionary you defined at the beginning of the function).

One way to do what you're trying to do is to allow a closure to be passed in to ***your*** function; something like this (I haven't tested this code):

`func getPlayerDataFromAPI(completion: (data: [String: AnyObject]) -> Void)`

Then, at the point you assign `jsonData = playerData`, you can "return" the data to the caller like this:

`completion(data: jsonData)`

Calling this function would look something like this:

```
getPlayerDataFromAPI() { (data) -> Void in 
    print(data)
}
```